# Manipulating text in a JPanel

Tags: text, jpanel

I have text that needs to be centered horizontally and 20px below the top of the window. Also, the target logo (g.fillOvals) need to be centered horizontally and vertically below the text. How do I do that? I know the g.drawString x and y coordinates edit the text but my variations do little to nothing. Thanks!

```
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        Font textFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 72);

        setFont(textFont);

        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(textFont);
        int ascend = fm.getAscent();
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        int sw = fm.stringWidth("Welcome to Target");

        g.drawString("Welcome to Target", w/2 - sw/2, h/2 + ascend/2);


        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval((w / 2) - 100, (w / 2) - 100, 200, 200);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillOval((w / 2) - 65, (w / 2) - 65, 130, 130);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval((w / 2) - 30, (w / 2) - 30, 60, 60);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
g.drawString("Welcome to Target", (w/2 - sw/2), (FONT_HEIGHT + 20));
```

Edit: Make your height of your font a constant so we can manage it better and allow more consistant programming.

```
final static String FONT_HEIGHT = 72;
g.fillOvals((w/2 - FONT_HEIGHT), 200, (w/2 FONT_HEIGHT), 200);
```

Comment: 20 cut the text off in the middle. All I saw was the bottom half of "Welcome to Target". I will continue to play around with the numbers though.

Comment: I got the text to line up right with 
`g.drawString("Welcome to Target", (w/2) - (sw/2), 20 + ascend);`

The Target logo is still too low though. It is constantly centered with the panel as I drag it around the frame.

Comment: What do you mean drag it around the frame? Edit: would you be able to provide a screenshot of what is happening.

Remember that the y value starts at the top of the graphics as well. So it's like your coding the graphics in the IV quadrant of a graph.

Comment: Bad wording on may part; the logo is fixed to a specific coordinate I think. I'm using netbeans 7.3 and I have a JFrame called TargetLogoUI.java and a JPanel called TagetLogoPanel.java. When I drop the panel into the frame and drag it around the logo stays in what I assume is a fixed coordinate. Does that make sense? haha

Edit: I can try

Comment: Are you using netbeans to create your GUI?

Comment: Could you provide all of your source code then? Using a program to create your interface isn't recommended because you're not going to learn anything from it, also it's never used in industry because you'll end up statically coding everything :\